# C++ Perfect Number. Need some help revising

Tags: c++, numbers, perfect-numbers

I need some help revising this. It keeps only displaying 0s as the temp. Thank you.

```
// A program to determine whether the input number is a perfect number
// A perfect number is defined by the sum of all its positive divisors excluding itself
// 28: 1+2+3+7+14 = 28. 

int perfect, limit, divisor;

cout << "Please enter a positive integer in order to define whether it is a perfect integer or not: " ;
 cin >> perfect;
 cout << endl;

 int temp = 0;
 int prevtemp = 0;
  limit = 1;
  divisor = 1;
 while (limit < perfect)
 {

  if ((perfect % divisor) == 0)
   {
   divisor = prevtemp;
   temp = prevtemp + temp;
   }

  limit++;
  divisor++;
 }

 if (perfect == temp)
  cout << "Your number is a perfect number!" << endl;
 else
  cout << "Your number is not a perfect number" << endl;

 return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I'd guess that in the code:

```
if ((perfect % divisor) == 0)
    divisor = prevtemp;
```

you intended this to be `prevtemp=divisor` instead. That fixes an obvious problem, but still leaves quite a bit that doesn't look like it's doing that you probably intended. For example, I can't quite figure out what `limit` is intended to accomplish -- you initialize it and increment it, but as far as I can see, you never *use* its value (well, I guess you use it, but its value is always the same as `divisor`'s so I'm not sure why you think you need both, or how `limit` makes any sense as its name).

Edit: It would make sense to have a `limit`. In particular, factors always come in pairs: one that's less than or equal to the square root of the number, and one that matches the first that's always greater than or equal to the square root of the number. As such, you don't need to scan all the way up to the number itself looking for factors -- you can set the square root of the number as the limit, and scan only up to that point. For each factor you find up to that point, the matching factor will be `perfect/divisor`. Since you've already gotten one working example, I guess I might as well just hope this isn't homework, and post an example as well:

```
bool is_perfect(int number) { 
    int limit = sqrt((double)number);
    int sum = 1;

    for (int i=2; i<=limit; i++)
        if (number % i == 0) 
            sum += i + number/i;
    return sum == number;
}
```

Comment: I am using limit on the while loop so that I can find all divisors that leave no remainders till perfect-1

Comment: I got it, I needed to put the  temp = prevtemp + temp; within the if block or else, it'll keep adding. I've edited to make this correct.

Comment: Haha, it is homework. What's wrong with getting some hw help? Again, thanks for your help, I appreciate it. I was thinking about using the sqrt as the limit, I just wanted a working prototype first.

Comment: @Jerry your function will not calculate sum correctly when number is a perfect square, neverless square numbers are not perfect numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You are never setting `prevtemp` to anything other than 0, so adding it to `temp` does nothing.

I believe you meant to say

```
if ((perfect % divisor) == 0) 
    temp += divisor; // not "divisor = prevtemp;"
```

The line "temp = prevtemp + temp" should also be removed with this solution; there is no longer any need for the `prevtemp` variable.

Also, there is no need to keep separate `limit` and `divisor` variables, since they are always the same. Just remove `limit` and change the loop condition to use `divisor`.

Also, as Mark Byers pointed out, the loop would be simpler to understand if you refactored it into a `for` loop rather than a `while`.

Comment: Ah.. thats what it was, I still need to fix some algorithm to make this work. THankS!

Comment: Yes, even with this fix it says 28 is not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are making it too complicated. Here's how you could do it:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < perfect; ++i)
{
    if (perfect % i == 0)
        total += i;
}

if (perfect == total)
    cout << "Your number is a perfect number!" << endl;
else
    cout << "Your number is not a perfect number" << endl;
```

Note that the running total is kept in a variable called `total` (you called this variable temp) and it is only increased when the number is an exact divisor.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm still confused on the local variables using for loops, so I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning anything to `prevtemp` after initializing it to `0`, so there is nothing to add to `temp` on the line that reads `temp = prevtemp + temp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,i=1,sum=0;
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin >> n;
    while(i<n){
        if(n%i==0)
            sum=sum+i;
        i++;
    }
    if(sum==n)
         cout << i  <<  " is a perfect number";
    else
         cout << i << " is not a perfect number";
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer. If there is something in particular that makes your answer an improvement, you should provide some explanation.